# FirebaseAdmin Messaging Fails to deliver APNs Silent Notification

Tags: vb.net, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-admin

I am using FirebaseAdmin.Messaging for my VB.net push notification delivery integration.

Everything works fine, we can send Android silent notification and normal notification we can also send APNs notification but we are unable send then receive the silent notification for APNs. I have tried couple of combinations that I saw on multiple threads but none of them worked. There is no error or issue when sending the notification we can successfully get notification token after the delivery but on mobile debugging side the payload doesn't reach.

Mobile integration team states that they can get the silent notification when below request invoked but this request structure is different than FirebaseAdmin.Messaging request structure.

Working request:

```
    {
  "to":"device_token",
    "priority": "high",
    "content_available": true,
     "data": {
       "id":1
      }
}
```

Failing request:

```
    {
   "token":"device_token",
   "condition":null,
   "data":null,
   "notification":null,
   "android":null,
   "webpush":null,
   "apns":{
      "headers":{
         "apns-priority":"5",
         "priority":"high",
         "content-available":"1",
         "content_available":"1",
         "apns-push-type'":"background"
      },
      "fcm_options":null,
      "payload":{
         "aps":{
            "badge":null,
            "category":null,
            "thread-id":null,
            "alert":null,
            "sound":null,
            "content-available":1,
            "mutable-content":1
         },
         "id":"test_value"
      }
   },
   "fcm_options":null,
   "topic":null
}
```

Failing request is an instance of FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message class. I have tried many combinations but none of them worked and I can't find any decent documentation regarding this matter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting with FCM support we couldnt figure out the exact issue.

We have found a workaround by giving Badge parameter as 0 The sound as empty and with only APNs Data payload. This is not considered as a silent notification but customer won't see a notification in his/her phone so it's same thing eventually.

Comment: Are they being delivered consistently with that change? setting badge as 0 removed the error, but not sure if it's consistent since I'm not always receiving the notif

Comment: Since this day I haven't got any issue. If you can debug from both mobile and server side it would be easier to debug by contacting with FCM support